# onClick event not respondong to its calling function

Tags: javascript

On the **`procesoA`** function I add a button to the HTML by using the variable **`r_html`**. That button has a onCick event added. When I try to execute that event (**`analizador`**) my console returns that **`analizador`** is not defined. I have tried to put it inside the **`procesoA`** function, but it is still not responding.

```js
let triviaA = () =>{
    divRespuestas.removeChild(botonA)
   let procesoA = (i,j) => {
        let p = preguntas_respuestas[i]
        let p_html = `${p[j].p}`
        bienvenida.innerText = p_html
        let r = p[j].r
        let r_html = r.map(r_button => `<button onclick="analizador" id="btn-opciones">${r_button}</button>`)
        let r_string = r_html.join(' ')
        divRespuestas.innerHTML = r_string
        
        
        
    }
    procesoA(0,0)
    function analizador() {
        alert('funciona')
    }

    
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not executing the function, you are only reference to it. To execute a function you must add `()` at the end of it's name.

The reason why `analizador` is undefined, is because that function is not in global scope, it's exists only in the anonymous function scope it was created in. When used `onclick` attribute, it can only execute functions from global scope.

So you have two choices:

1. move `analizador` function into global scope
2. use `myelement.addEventListener('click', analizador);`

The latter is always preferred.

```js
let triviaA = () =>{
  divRespuestas.removeChild(botonA);
  let procesoA = (i,j) => {
      let p = preguntas_respuestas[i];
      let p_html = `${p[j].p}`;
      bienvenida.innerText = p_html;
      let r = p[j].r;
      r.map((r_button, n) => {
        // create element instead of using text for innerHTML
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.addEventListener("click", analizador);
        button.textContent = r_button;
        button.id = "btn-opciones_" + n; //create unique ID
        divRespuestas.appendChild(button);
      });
  };
  procesoA(0,0);
  function analizador () {
      alert('funciona');
  }
};
```

P.S.
Another mistake is that you are using `id="btn-opciones"` for the buttons, `id` attribute supposed to be unique in the same document.